# Use diskutil without firmware password

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, firmware

Diskutil found some problems on my drive that need to be fixed in recovery mode. However the it department installed a password in the firmware. Is there anyway to start diskutil without the firmwarepassword? It only needs to fix some issue is in the partition table. 
I tried to launch in single user modus. But apparently this only works if you don't install a firmware password.

Comment: The IT department probably set a firmware password for a reason. Why don't you reach out to them for help?

Comment: @patrix they often do weird things with macs, that cost a lot of time to fix. Like installing software that cannot be updated. Setting this password was smart for most users though.

Comment: If it is company hardware, have them solve the drive problem as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the firmware password, you cannot boot into recovery mode, and thus you cannot make distil bypass the protection. Even worse, there's no way to reset a firmware password than going to recovery mode to disable it (which requires the original password), or taking it to the Apple store with the original receipt so they can disable it for you.

If the problem has to be fixed, talk to the IT department and have them fix it for you.